# JPA - Reload @OneToMany dependencies automatically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this scenario:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Long id;
}

public class User extends AbstractEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Dependent> dependents;
}

public class Dependent extends AbstractEntity {
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn
     private User user;
}
```

When I try to `insert()` a new `User` instance with some `Dependent`'s that already are present in database, what means they have the `id` field populated, I get a `Detached entity passed to persist` exception.

It can be solved by manually loading all the `Dependent`s from database, but it don't look right.

I would like to know how to make JPA automatically load them when `id` field is populated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA API use:

```
EntityManager.merge(T t)
```

instead of

```
EntityManager.persist(Object object)
```

Since you are using CascadeType.ALL, when you use merge, the JPA Provider will try to update the Users (in case they exists in database) or will create new ones.

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html.